# XQuery how to represent a string as a number?

Tags: string, numbers, xquery, marklogic

Let us assume that we have a string `let $string:='red color'`, which is usually consist of 2 words. Is there a way to represent this string as a number **Or** sequence of numbers ? I'm using XQuery and Marklogic.

Comment: It’s not clear what you’re asking. Strings aren’t numbers. If you want to count the number of tokens use fn:tokenize(), or similar.

Comment: It seems that you didn't understood what I'm asking for. Look at my answer

Comment: Very weird question. You don't give a purpose for doing this. My guess is you just want a hash like an xdmp:md5 call to change the string to a fairly unique numeric value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution of how to represent a string as a sequence of numbers. The function That I found represent a string with a sequence of numbers which is fine in my case.
The function `fn:string-to-codepoints("pla pla pla")` returns the sequence of Unicode code points that constitute a string.
[image: result]

Comment: That's not a number. It's a sequence of numbers - which is not what you state in your original problem statement (post). If you just concatenate them together, you can have collisions. You'll have to pad them to keep the original meaning(whicih becomes a big number and you may hit limitations). Consider this: MarkLogic = 77,97,114,107,76,111,103,105,99 which equals: 77971141077611110310599 if you smush them together. However, The code-point for ṵrk˹іĶɗ if smushed together is exactly the same...

Comment: I asked for one number, but when I found this function that returns a sequence of numbers it worked for the problem that I'm working on. Without having to pad them I didn't mention anything about padding numbers.

Comment: Question edited ..  **number Or sequence of numbers**